# Load or Stress Testing in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am using nodejs with express.

I have created a signup  form with some fields. I want to check when 1000 user signups on same time. What will happen? 
Is there is any module available or any simple example. How to enter fake data.

How can i write a test case for that. I googled it, but didn't get result.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [faker](https://www.npmjs.org/package/faker) to generate the fake data and [request](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request) to send the data to the server.  You can use `async.each` to asynchronously do 1000 signups at the same time.

```
var faker = require('faker');
var async = require('async');

var number_of_signups = 1000;
var identities = [];

for (var i=0; i < number_of_signups; i++) {
  identities.push({
    name: faker.name.findName(),
    email: faker.internet.email(),
    password: faker.internet.password()
  });
}

function submit(identity, callback) {
  var opts = {
    url: 'http://youdomain.com/signup-endpoint',
    method: 'POST',
    json: identity
  };
  request(opts, function(err, connection, body) {
    if(err) return callback(err);
    callback();
  });
}

async.each(identities, submit, function(err) {
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log('done...');
  process.exit();
});
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use this.. i mean how to request data using faker

Comment: giving me error  like this on my endpoint .. TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON